# Filtering list and classify according to ID

Tags: python, list

I have a list of dictionaries in my python app. A sample list is as follows:

```
[
        {
            "rule": {"uid": "4"},
            "layer": {"name": "Premium Network", "type": "access-layer"},
            "package": {"name": "Standard"},
        },
        {
            "rule": {"uid": "10"},
            "layer": {"name": "Premium Network", "type": "access-layer"},
            "package": {"name": "Standard"},
        },
        {
            "rule": {"uid": "2"},
            "layer": {"name": "Premium Network", "type": "access-layer"},
            "package": {"name": "Premium"},
        },
        {
            "rule": {"uid": "5"},
            "layer": {"name": "Premium Network", "type": "access-layer"},
            "package": {"name": "Premium"},
        },
        {
            "rule": {"uid": "78"},
            "layer": {"name": "Premium Network", "type": "access-layer"},
            "package": {"name": "Premium"},
        },
    ]
```

I want to filter the list in such a way where for each package name I get the UID in a list.

I already have a class 'Rule' with attributes policy name and uids to store the data.

In my example above I should get two Rule objects:

```
1. 1st rule object with name Standard and uids ["4", "10"]
2. 2nd rule object with name Premium and uids ["2", "5", "78"]
```

I achieved this with the use of a for loop and flags but I was wondering if there was a better way to do this using filters in  Python or any other better way than a long for loop with flags?

Below is the code i used to achieve this functionality:

```
@staticmethod
def fetch_rules(object_name, filtered_list):
    access_rules_uid = []
    rules = []
    current_policy_processing = None

    # If list is not empty, proceed
    for rule in filtered_list:

        # Get the policy name
        policy = rule["package"]["name"]

        # Flag the current policy to
        # know when to switch
        if current_policy_processing is None:
            current_policy_processing = policy

        # If policy name has changed
        if current_policy_processing != policy:

            # Create new rule object and assign data
            rl = Rule(object_name, current_policy_processing, [])
            rl.access_rules_uid.extend(access_rules_uid)
            rules.append(rl)
            # Change old policy name to new
            current_policy_processing = policy

            # Clear uid array
            access_rules_uid.clear()

        access_rules_uid.append(rule["rule"]["uid"])

    if access_rules_uid:

        # This is to add the last item
        # Create new rule object and assign data
        rl = Rule(object_name, current_policy_processing, [])
        rl.access_rules_uid.extend(access_rules_uid)
        rules.append(rl)

        # Cleanup
        # Change old policy name to none
        current_policy_processing = None

        # Clear uid array
        access_rules_uid.clear()

    return rules
```

Comment: Can you show us your code for getting this output ?

Comment: Hi @AlexisG, i posted the code i used to achieve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
named_rules = [(a["rule"]["uid"], a["package"]["name"]) for a in yourlist]
groups = {}
for rule, name in named_rules:
    if name in groups:
        groups[name].append(name)
    else:
        groups[name] = [name]

print(groups)
```

A one liner to parse the input, and then group the parsed input into groups as your requirement.

I will leave parsing into your formatted output for you

---

You could (and should) skip the one liner, and parse directly. I just wanted to make the example more readable.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) like this:

```
def transform(array):
    package_name_getter = lambda item: item['package']['name']
    sorted_array = sorted(array, key=package_name_getter)
    return [
        Rule(
            package_name,
            [
                item['rule']['uid']
                for item in items
            ],
        )
        for package_name, items in itertools.groupby(sorted_array, key=package_name_getter)
    ]
```